# bind onclick event to element by attribute

Tags: jquery, binding, attributes

Trying to add click event to all elements with the same attribute:

```
$("[data-action='set_to_charged']").on('click',function(){
        admin.function_to_fire(this);
    });
```

Getting: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Why?

Comment: I think problem is this `admin.function_to_fire(this);`, see on which line error is?

Comment: error line is on $("[data-action='set_to_charged']").on('click',function(){

Comment: What version of jQuery have you loaded?  Is `$` defined in this scope?  I'm sure the error is telling you exactly where something is "undefined."  When you break on that line in the debugger, which object is it?

Comment: Can you share the code a in a fiddle:Works for me :Check this out @AsafMaoz http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/bu7afmkv/

Comment: 2.0.1 jquery. Fixed, problem was with the .on(...   => changed to .click(...